# Remove comma from numbers in <f:validateLongRange> error message

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

In JSF and Primefaces have a simple Integer input with a maximum and minimum range.

```
<p:inputText id="fooBar"
         value="#{foo.bar}"
         placeholder="fooBar"
         required="true">
  <f:converter converterId="javax.faces.Integer"/>
  <f:validateLongRange minimum="500" maximum="3000"/>
</p:inputText>
```

What I'm trying to do is remove the comma from 3,000 in the resulting error message when the user enters a value outside of the range. Is it possible? If so how? For example I want it to say

```
FooBar: The value must be between 500 and 3000
```

not

```
FooBar: The value must be between 500 and 3,000
```

Edit:
Some additional information that may be useful.The application is using localization. This is the english version of the message. I am overwriting the default message produced by this validator.

```
javax.faces.validator.LongRangeValidator.NOT_IN_RANGE = {2}: The value must be between {0} and {1}
```

Comment: cannot reproduce it. maybe its a locale thing?

Comment: @Apostolos we have localization enabled. This is the english version obviously. I'll edit my post to mention that.